# Core Data Relationship with JSON Data 100% CPU takes long time

Tags: ios, json, core-data, cpu-usage, magicalrecord

I'm currently working on an iOS App that takes some JSON from the Internet and packs it into a Core Data database. I'm working also with MagicalRecord.

There are 2 Objects in this case:

1. Site - has an ID an can handle different HazardousMaterials
2. HazardousMaterials - has an ID, UID

The JSON of the "Sites" looks like this, just with 120 entries, the array "HazardousMaterials" contains the UIDs of the Object "HazardousMaterial" that the Site can handle:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    HazardousMaterials: [
    279, 315, 412, 434, 495, 502, 681, 696,
    997, 1009, 1094, 1162, 1191, 1391, 1412,
    1482, 1755, 1776, 1789, 2037, 2045, 2152,
    2186
    ],
},
```

Now I'm downloading the JSON dictionary and parse the data:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in sites) {
     Sites *site = [Sites createEntity];
     site.uid = [dictionary valueForKey: @"Id"];

     NSArray *hazardousMaterials = [dictionary objectForKey: @"HazardousMaterials"];
     for (NSNumber *hazardID in hazardousMaterials) {
          [site addHazardousMaterialsObject: [HazardousMaterial findFirstByAttribute: @"uid" withValue: hazardID]];
     }
}
[self saveContext];
```

But the process takes 100% CPU and on older iPhones like iPhone 4(s) or iPod touch it just freezes after a time, how can I make that process faster/easier? Any Ideas?

Comment: are you sorting an array with your [HazardousMaterial findFirstByAttribute: @"uid" withValue: hazardID]

Comment: First thanks very much, with the background thread the progress animation doesn't freeze anymore, but still the process takes more than 3 minutes on an iPod.

Comment: No "findFirstByAttribute" is the magical record method to find the first object in the core data database with the uid i need